# ImportError: No module named xgboost

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

When I tried import from python terminal I get this error, although I followed all the steps to install xgboost, somehow python is unable to get the package details.I am relatively new to python, I could easily install numpy and pandas packages,I used this link for installation on MACOSX http://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build.html

```
>>> import xgboost
   Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
   ImportError: No module named xgboost
```

When I did pip install xgboost, I am getting this error,

```
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/h7/pyph_7qj6171tqp50cf2xc7m0000gn/T/pip-build-TEvbD6/xgboost/
```

I am getting this on printing sys path,

> > > print sys.path

['', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC']

Comment: Well, the module is there but there is no such class. Maybe it's in a submodule? e.g. `from xgboost.xgbclassifier import XGBClassifier`

Comment: You didn't name your local file `xgboost.py`, did you?

Comment: ImportError: No module named 'xgboost.xgbclassifier', I tried using your command, it returned this.

Comment: @JohnGordon no! Running it on jupyter notebook, name of the file is different. I am new to python, I need the classifier to be imported

Comment: If you can't even import xgboost, then the installation must have gone wrong.  What directory did you install it in?

Comment: @JohnGordon, cd $HOME

Comment: Did you add its installation directory to your `PYTHONPATH` environment variable?  Try this command from inside python: `import sys; print(sys.path)`

Comment: @JohnGordon no, I don't know how to do that, could you please tell me how to?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128740/discussion-between-shobhika-and-john-gordon).

Answer (score 32, accepted):

First you need to get control of your python environment. Download the [homebrew](http://brew.sh/) python by pasting these into a fresh terminal window

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

here you will be prompterd to enter your password. After homebrew is installed, install python with `brew install python`. Please check your installation with `brew doctor` and follow homebrew's suggestions.

Now, with a fresh terminal window, install xgboost from pip. Open [terminal](http://www.macworld.co.uk/feature/mac-software/get-more-out-of-os-x-terminal-3608274/) and paste this in:

```
pip install xgboost
```

Comment: I do not have setup.py file in my xgboost directory, I tried cloning the directory from github.

Comment: Shobhikas-MacBook-Air:xgboost shobhikapanda$ python setup.py install
python: can't open file 'setup.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: I got the setup.py from this download folder <https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xgboost/>, I ran the script setup.py , I am getting this error, File "setup.py", line 29, in <module>
    LIB_PATH = libpath['find_lib_path']()
  File "xgboost/libpath.py", line 45, in find_lib_path
    'List of candidates:\n' + ('\n'.join(dll_path)))
__builtin__.XGBoostLibraryNotFound: Cannot find XGBoost Libarary in the candicate path, did you install compilers and run build.sh in root path?

Comment: @shobhika I updated my answer. Please try reinstalling python as I suggest.

Comment: How to link package installation with python?

Answer (score 12):

I had the same issue. I tried everything but the only solution that worked for me to was to install the whl file directly from here : 
http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#xgboost

then you can do :

```
pip install yourFile.whl
```

On windows I managed to just double click on the whl file and install it

Good luck

Answer (score 11):

FYI if you are using anaconda dist'n then need to do

```
conda install -c conda-forge xgboost
```

Answer (score 10):

Use conda install in Anaconda Powershell Prompt then use pip install

```
conda install -c conda-forge xgboost
pip install xgboost
```

Answer (score 9):

Try running

```
pip install xgboost
```

in Anaconda prompt; it's important that you do it in Anaconda prompt so it is in same location as the Python you're using.

Answer (score 8):

```
git clone --recursive https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost
cd xgboost
sudo cp make/minimum.mk ./config.mk;
sudo make -j4;
sh build.sh
cd python-package
python setup.py install
```

Atleast Now I can import xgboost from terminal on macosx, I haven't been able to import it in jupyter notebook as yet.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your solutions and when I run the "sh build.sh". It couldn't find the file and shows "No such file or directory". Do you know how to solve it?

Answer (score 8):

I tried

```
pip install xgboost
```

and

```
pip3 install xgboost
```

But it doesn't work

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'xgboost'

Finally I solved
Try this in the Jupyter Notebook cell

```
import sys
!{sys.executable} -m pip install xgboost
```

Results:

```
Collecting xgboost
  Using cached xgboost-1.4.1-py3-none-win_amd64.whl (97.8 MB)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from xgboost) (1.5.2)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from xgboost) (1.19.2)
Installing collected packages: xgboost
Successfully installed xgboost-1.4.1
```

Answer (score 4):

Write this on the terminal of Jupyter:

```
conda install -c anaconda py-xgboost
```

Answer (score 2):

On Pycharm you can go to Pycharm > Prefernces, go to the interpreter you have and install the `xgboost` package.

Answer (score 1):

Give the following commands a try.

```
pip install xgboost
pip install plotly
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the second command?

Answer (score 1):

All you need within Jupyter Notebook cell is:
try running

```
import sys
!{sys.executable} -m pip install xgboost
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Open the terminal
2. Type *pip install xgboost* and hit enter.

Make sure your internet connection is good.

Do not forget to crosscheck the successful installation of it in jupyter.

Comment: The OP has already tried to install xgboost but getting another error.

Answer (score 0):

---

if you run

> pip install xgboost

in command line and no result, run the same command in ***jupyter*** notebook.

Answer (score 0):

for ubuntu 18 LTS, this worked for me.
cmake is a pre-requiste to it, so if you havent you would need to install that, currently at print its version 3.10 + minimum.

in terminal:
sudo snap install cmake --classic

in jupyter notebook(if terminal just edit it)
import sys
!{sys.executable} -m pip install xgboost

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had multiple Python versions, and I was installing it in the wrong one.

```
pip install xgboost
```

installed the module on Python 3.7, but I needed to install it with Python 3.10. What I run was:

```
py -m pip install xgboost
```

which worked, since "py" is my binary for Python 3.10. The suitable command if you have multiple Python versions may be different depending on which version you have. In Ubuntu, for example, this worked for me:

```
python3.8 -m pip3 install xgboost
```

Answer (score -1):

On Windows 10, And if using Anaconda, below is another alternative that's how I did it:

- Run the Anaconda as Administrator.
- Launch Powershell Prompt from Navigator
- `pip install xgboost`

[image]